# Phonegap build - Android - Application not installed error

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

for literally almost 2 years, I have had an app that I have been incrementally adding to and using PhoneGap Build to compile.  Yesterday, that all stopped working.

Every time I try to install the application on a device/simulator running <4.3 I get the "Application Not Installed..." error.  There is no reason to it.

I have tried removing all the test applications from the device that might cause a name/id mismatch, and I even removed all the builds off PhoneGap Build and started essentially from scratch.

They install fine on anything newer then 4.3.  What am I missing here.

For reference, the app ID is: 1050754

This actually started when I tried to upload a new version of the app to Google Play, and devices <4.3 were having problems installing the APK.  Help!

Comment: Whats in your config file and how do we use the app id to have a look?

Comment: This happens if you change something crucial in the config, like the com.nameofdev.nameofapp and, importantly, if you try to upgrade from a debug version to a release version or vice versa.

Comment: find the android.manifest file inside platform folder. see what's the minimum and target SDK version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by Phonegap Build internally.  It was a build server problem with their certificate signing mechanism.